Launch a subset of docker compose services (containers). Use a script?
How to start only some containers from the list of services present in a docker-compose.yml file?
MS Visual Studio supports it, see here.
This question has already been asked: docker-compose up for only certain containers but I'm not satisfied with the answers: I want to start several services in one command.
If it can't be done with one simple command I can use a Python script or a Powershell one (powershell v7 if possible) to do the job.

Did you try supplying multiple service names to docker up (eg. docker up -d service1 service3)? What happens when you do?

...it works! docker compose up service1 service4 does the job. Just write it as an answer and I'll accept it.
